# Trying to find json/geojson for mapbox vector file

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to recreate a local version of https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/ which loads the data from 'mapbox://mapbox.04w69w5j'. I am trying to find the loaded data in json or geojson to download locally and modify the data to see how it will work with my custom data.

I am having trouble finding it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given a vector tile endpoint, it is not, in general, possible to download that data as a single GeoJSON file.